# Hide a view in the last group in expandablelistview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I've modified this [tutorial](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/) by adding few extra views, what I'm trying to do now is to set the visibility of the image views to invisible in the last group only,

The group layout is this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/laptop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text=" " />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the code where I'm trying to hide the view is this

```
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String laptopName = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item, null);
    }
    TextView item = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.laptop);
    item.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    item.setText(laptopName);
    ImageView delete = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete);

    if (groupPosition ==  getGroupCount()-1 ) {
        delete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }


        delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                int gpos = groupPosition;
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);
                builder.setMessage("Do you want to remove?");
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                            }
                        });
                builder.setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });


    return convertView;
}
```

The problem happens only after scrolling the list, it looks like it's related to the recycling of the view and I'm not sure how should I handle it, can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct and your views are recycled which is why you must explicitly set the view to `VISIBLE` or not each time you return the view. Try something like this.

```
if (groupPosition ==  getGroupCount()-1 ) {
    delete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}else {
    delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```